# What is the class/file that creates invoices in openerp 7

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

Im new in openerp, and i need to crete an hash when the invoice is created and add that hash to database.
I've already created the hash, i just need to know where can i edit the method that creates invoices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is called Create, overwrite it:

```
def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):

    values['your_hash_column'] = 'your_hash_result'

    res = super(YourClassName, self).create(cr, uid, ids, values, context)

    return res
```

Be sure that the "YourClassName" is the name of the class that you are using.

Explanation: The create method use the dictionary "values" to append the results in the db, if you add to that dict a new value (in that case your hash) and you call it again with super, you will have the same result with that value, then you return it.

Comment: the file is sale.py am i right?
i know is good pratice overwrite it, but i'm not creating an addon or anything else. i just need to create the hash when i create the invoice and save it on the database (already have done the hash and saved it to database, but its not enough!).
So, i need to edit that last step to add one more field on create invoice.

thanks for reply :)

Comment: No, its the account_invoice.py from account module. Anyway you have to overwrite create!

Comment: Sorry didnt explain why, you have to overwrite create because its a function from all the models and not only invoice, even if you do or not a module.

Hope it helps